# Codeigniter login (auth) only with username (without password)

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

Is there a way to make authentication into Codeigniter, only with username, not using a password?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Hope you're not trying to store anything secure though. The terse Datamapper ORM solution would be something like the following. Adapt to Active Record if you need to.

### The CodeIgniter

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    function try_username(){
        $p = $this->input->post();
        if($p){
            $u = new User();
            $u->where('username', $p['username'])->get();
            if($u->exists()){
                $data = array("loggedin" => true "username" => $p['username']);
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('logged_in_controller');
            }

        }   
    }
}
```

### Now your HTML:

```
<form action='login/try_username' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='username'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well of course if you do not require security you could easily set your session based upon a single username. This is just as much possible in Codeigniter as in just PHP or other framework/language.

controller example:

```
function authenticate()
{
    // check postdata
    if ($this->input->post('username')):
       if (!$this->auth_model->login($this->input->post('username',true))):
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Bad username!');
       else:
            // go to user page or such...
       endif;
    endif;
    redirect('login'); // take user back to login page
}
```

In above example I assume you have a model (auth_model) that checks database for username and sets login session for you. If user is not logged in then you get an error message and is sent back to login page...

Comment: tnx, but looks like my model does not allows me to login without sending a password...

Comment: Well can't you just rewrite your model then? If You add your model code for authentication we might be able to help you modify it.

Answer (score 0):

you need only username = abc@gmail.com

public function login_ulogin($identity, $remember=FALSE)
    {

```
    $this->trigger_events('pre_login');



    $this->trigger_events('extra_where');

    $query = $this->db->select('username,group_id, email, id, password, active, last_login')
        ->where('username', $identity)
        ->from('users')
        ->get();



    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {

        $user = $query->row();


        $password = TRUE;//$this->hash_password_db($user->id, $password);

        if ($password === TRUE)
        {

            $this->set_session($user);

            $this->update_last_login($user->id);

            $this->clear_login_attempts($identity);

            if ($remember && $this->config->item('remember_users', 'ion_auth'))
            {
                $this->remember_user($user->id);
            }

            $this->trigger_events(array('post_login', 'post_login_successful'));
            $this->set_message('login_successful');

            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    //Hash something anyway, just to take up time
    //$this->hash_password($password);

    $this->increase_login_attempts($identity);

    $this->trigger_events('post_login_unsuccessful');
    $this->set_error('login_unsuccessful');

    return FALSE;
}
```